# What other theistic positions support open theism besides Christianity?

Tags: reference-request, theology, philosophy-of-religion, omniscience, libertarianism-free-will

[Open theism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_theism) is a libertarian view of free will claiming that God’s omniscience does not extend to knowing the actual choices of free human agents.  It is a theory of “dynamic omniscience”.

This concept became popular in 1980 with Richard Rice’s book *[The Openness of God](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Openness_of_God.html?id=_GzGAAAACAAJ)* although the history of the idea in Christianity goes back to the 4th century [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_theism#Historical_development):

> The first known post-biblical Christian writings advocating concepts
>   similar to open theism with regard to the issue of foreknowledge are
>   found in the writings of Calcidius, a 4th-century interpreter of
>   Plato. It was affirmed in the 16th century by Socinus, and in the
>   early 18th century by Samuel Fancourt and by Andrew Ramsay (an
>   important figure in Methodism). In the 19th century several
>   theologians wrote in defense of this idea, including Isaak August
>   Dorner, Gustav Fechner, Otto Pfleiderer, Jules Lequier, Adam Clarke,
>   Billy Hibbard, Joel Hayes, T.W. Brents, and Lorenzo D. McCabe.
>   Contributions to this defense increased as the century drew to a
>   close.

Outside of Christianity, Cicero expressed similar views according to the [Information Philosopher](http://www.informationphilosopher.com/freedom/history/):

> If there is free will, all things do not happen according to fate; if
>   all things do not happen according to fate, there is not a certain
>   order of causes; and if there is not a certain order of causes,
>   neither is there a certain order of things foreknown by God.

I am looking for references, such as the Cicero quote above, of other theistic positions supporting ideas similar to open theism besides those expressed within Christianity.

Comment: Similar view in early Islam was called [Qadariyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qadariyah), but it was explicitly condemned by Muhammad, apparently Zoroastrians held it too. For Buddhism see [Why the Buddha Did Not Discuss "The Problem of Free Will and Determinism" by Gowans](https://philpapers.org/rec/GOWWTB). The dilemma is too "Western" to be relevant there, since Buddha rejected the notion of "self" there is room for indeterminism but not for "free will".

Comment: @Conifold How can I get more than the citation for the Gowans paper? Sounds interesting. Thanks

Comment: @CriglCragl Here is a pdf of [Repetti edited Buddhist Perspectives on Free Will](https://philarchive.org/archive/REPBPO-2), Gowans's essay is first. You may want to look at other ones too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed theism is a consequence of a God out of time, IE, an eternal/unchanging God.  Most Christian conceptions of God put God out of time.  Two contemporary Christian theologians who hold by a God in time are Richard Swinbourne, and John Polkinghorne.

Most of the OT was written with a conception of a God inside time, who changes and acts.

Zoroastrianism explicitly held that human actions were entirely free, which would be open theism.

Multi-deity pantheism also puts Gods inside time, and is an open theism.

As is Shamanism.

Comment: Good point on where to look with a God in time and examples using Zoroastrianism, pantheism and Shamanism.